# How can I make sure I can run Python in Powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

I have looked for some questions about this on Stackoverflow.
I am using Python 2.7.11.

When I open Powershell and type in python I get an intended error:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What I found on stackoverflow is this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27")
```

When I run this Python works. However, what can I do so I don't have to enter [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27") every time I run poweshell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that python directory is not in system path variable,to put it there.
1.Open control panel
2.search for env, you will see edit system environment variables in the results.
3.click then select environment variable and edit the PATH variable ,just write the fulll path to python directory which is most likely C:\Python27; save it in there and you are good to go.